# MongoDB query on n'th element(variable index) of subdocument array

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I query on the `n`th element of a subdocument array in MongoDB where `n` is variable?

Suppose, I've documents like bellow:

```
{
  list:[
    {
      a: true,
      b: 'abc'
    },
    {
      a: false,
      b: 'def'
    },
    {
      a: true,
      b: 'ghi'
    },
  ]
}
```

1. Query 1: I need to find all documents which have `a: false` on the 1st element of `list`(i.e. `'list.0.a': false`)
2. Query 2: I need to find all documents which have `a: false` on the 2nd element of `list`(i.e. `'list.1.a': false`)
3. Query 3: I need to find all documents which have `a: false` on the 3rd element of `list`(i.e. `'list.2.a': false`)

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: Why not just run query like

 db.collection.find({ "list.1.a": false})

Comment: @Caconde I tried deconstructing array with `unwind` but it doesn't help. @mickl 's answer works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to use aggregation expressions in your query, [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable, [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to take nth element of an array:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $let: {
            vars: { fst: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$list", 0 ] } },
            in: { $eq: [ "$$fst.a", false ] }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks! Anyway, is there any performance issue with `$expr` operator?

Comment: @MostafizRahman I don't think so - it's just because there are two types of operators: the old ones for querying and the new ones from aggregation so it's a kind of bridge between these two worlds