# Mongo updateMany with $set agreggation, self reference and array member gives empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

With Mongo 4.2.5 and this collection

```js
db.foo.insert({foo:["bar", "baz"]})
```

when trying to copy the "baz" in the array to a new field named foobaz like this in the shell:

```js
db.foo.updateMany({}, [{$set:{foobaz: "$foo.1"}}])
```

I get an object like this

```js
{
   _id: fooid,
   foo: ["bar", "baz"],
   foobaz: []//empty array instead of "baz"
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) since `$set` requires Aggregation Framework's array access syntax:

```
db.foo.updateMany({}, [{$set:{foobaz: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$foo", 1 ] }}}])
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew about that. If element in the array are also nested object, how do i get the path after $arrayElemAt ?

Comment: @VincentJ you can try with $let like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599310/mongodb-query-on-nth-elementvariable-index-of-subdocument-array/57600986#57600986